# Team Foundation Server plugin WorkItemChangedEvent

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to create a TFS plugin that binds to the WorkItemChangedEvent and prevents the change based on some rules I will implement later. I have found some example code online and this is what I've got so far, however I would expect this to prevent all changes to work items but it doesn't seem to have any effect. There is no errors in the event viewer for TFS.

```
public class CwoWorkItemChangedEventHandler : ISubscriber
{
    public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
    {
        return new[] { typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent) };
    }

    public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType,
        object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage,
        out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
    {
        statusCode = 0;
        properties = null;
        statusMessage = String.Empty;
        return EventNotificationStatus.ActionDenied;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return "CwoWorkItemChangedEventHandler"; }
    }

    public SubscriberPriority Priority
    {
        get { return SubscriberPriority.High; }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work item changed event is not a decision out and you can't deny it.

But the time that you have the event it has already happened. Only some events have decision points.

Comment: Ah ok thats fair enough. Is there a reason this event is not firing though? I tried putting logging in the event but I'm not seeing the logs